# How to permanently set screen brightness level in Ubuntu 12.04 on Dell Vostro 2420 laptop?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, dell

On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Dell Vostro 2420 laptop, each time I start Ubuntu, the screen brightness is set to the maximum level, which gives a high glare. (I have recently installed Ubuntu on the laptop, but did not change any default settings related to brightness, IIRC.) I am currently lowering the brightness manually each time after starting, using the System Settings icon on the left of the screen. Looking for a permanent way to set it to a lower value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After you set the brightness to your desired level open up a terminal and check what the brightness is set to by using

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Then you can take that value and

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Right above `exit 0` add

```
echo your_value_here > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

and then save the file.  This will permanently set the brightness to your value as rc.local is executed at each reboot.

**Note:** This only works if you have a file named brightness in `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/`

Comment: Thanks, have made that change. Not rebooted to test it yet. Will do so shortly and then reply here whether it worked. Pretty sure it will, since I saw the value in the file change even when I changed the brightness via System Settings.

Comment: I rebooted, and the changes have taken effect. Thanks!

Comment: @TooBrightScreen Glad it worked, please feel free to mark it as answered so others could easily find the solution.

Comment: How to mark it as answered? I looked in most places in this screen, also hovered mouse over most of the icons, but don't see any way to mark it as answered. Do I need to be above some value for reputation to mark it?

Comment: @TooBrightScreen [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Also, the value for the brightness of keyboard backlight is located in `/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness` (replace asus::kbd_backlight with the name of the folder for your keyboard)

Answer (score 2):

Install `backlight` on your system.

Place the command `xbacklight -set value` in your startup.

It will automatically do the job for you. Hope this helps!

Comment: You mean install `xbacklight`?

Answer (score 0):

@bigbash after setting the brightness to a desired set value i am typing this command, /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness, did the way u have suggested but it is not working.One more thing what ever value i set for brightness from settings after putting the above command always i am getting the same value i.e 15.

Comment: That means you have more than one display output. Or at least, you did plug at least one before. Try looking at `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video1/brightness`. I hope this helps.